# php: difference between to isset methods?

Tags: php, isset

not sure how i should name the title of the post.

i'm having a submitbutton on my page that's creating a folder for me. as soon as i press it. the site AUTOMATICALLY refreshes. There's no script set in my document that says the page should refresh. it just happens when i submit anything, right?

```
if (isset($_POST['createDir'])) {   
    $dir = $_POST['dirname'];
    $targetfilename = PATH . '/' . $dir;
    if (!is_dir($targetfilename)) {
        mkdir($targetfilename);
        chmod($targetfilename, 0777);
    } else {
        echo "Folder exists!";
    }   
}
```

a bit further down in my script i have the same thing to delete files and folders.

```
if (isset($_POST['deleteBtn'])) {
    chmod(PATH, 0777);
    foreach ($_POST['deletefiles'] as $value) {
            unlink(PATH . '/' . $value);
    }
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT='0'>"; //doesn't work without it!
}
```

if i click the submitbutton to delete a folder the pages DON'T refresh. Even though the script works and the files get deleted. Where is difference between the script creating a folder and the other one to delete files. I actually don't really get it.

regards matt

Comment: Wild guess: _"a bit further down"_ => after you already showed the list?

Comment: so the "create folder" and "delete folder" buttons are placed in a form, right? And if you click one button, the page is reloaded by the form, but if you press the other one nothing happens and the page isn't reloaded? Or do you mean that the pages _are_ reloaded but don't always show updated conten??

Comment: exactly. and I'm not sure if just the content doesn't show up properly or the page doesn't refresh. However if i don't manually refresh the page with the meta-refresh the content where i list the files don't update. The file get's deleted but the the LIST (it's a list with all my files) doesn't update.

Comment: _"I'm not sure if just the content doesn't show up properly or the page doesn't refresh"_. How can you not know?! Did you see the browser loading icon in your browser or not ;) ?

Comment: @wrikken a bit further down means: i have the script to delete the files and a few lines underneath that i'll have my function which prints out the html form with the list-checkboxes.

Comment: Just another question, just to be sure, does the code list the files _before_ executing the delete command?

Comment: yep. i'm having one page with a form element to create a folder. it contains a textfield to input a name and btn to fire the create folder command. underneath i print out another form which lists all my files and folders with checkboxes. if i check a box and hit the submitbutton the folder/file gets deleted. however if create a folder the list automatically refreshes and shows the new content. if i delete a folder the list doesn't refresh automatically. (the folder is deleted but the list shows still the same contents) If i refresh the page everything's fine.

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry ok, it does a RELOAD! but the list doesn't refresh!

Comment: @mathiregister Ok, say when does your code _read_ the directory contents, using `readdir()`, `dir()`, or something similar? Does it do that _before_ the `unlink()` call, or is `unlink()` called before reading the directory contents? Again, I'm not talking about generating the HTML, but about the function calls in PHP.

Comment: i have one admin.php file and the structure looks like this: http://cl.ly/1nUn

Comment: @mathiregister ok, what does that "run through all files" at line 12 do? Is it building a list of all the files to be used in the createList() call?

Comment: the "run through all files" just opens the dir, runs a while loop and creates an array of all the files in the dir. i pass that array into my createList function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after our extended conversation in the comments, I think I can now safely say that this is what's going wrong. Considering that this is the order your code executes:

1. if the create-folder button was pressed, create the folder
2. run through the directory and store all filepaths in a variable
3. if the delete-folder/file button was pressed, remove the folder/file
4. display the directory content retrieved in step 2.

In that case, the error is that the above step 2 and 3 *should be switched*! If you first list all the files, and then delete some, it will not be reflected in the output since that list as obtained just before deletion.

In general, you want to first handle any user command to create/delete/modify files and directories, and only at the last moment list the must up-to-date state of the filesystem.